# Spring Cloud Stream multiple function definitions

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, reactive, spring-cloud-function

Is it possible to have reactive SCS application using functional (`spring.cloud.function`) style with multiple, separate functions / bindings? All examples I have found always register only one functional bean with default bindings `input, output`. I would like to register multiple, each with its own bindings.

Traditionally this could be done using `spring-cloud-stream-reactive` but it is now deprecated in favor of functional support.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in the latest snapshot and we'll be making RC1 shortly (were busy with the conference). Here is the [link to the relevant docs](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-stream.adoc#multiple-functions-in-a-single-application).
Basically you define as many function beans as you want and you declare how many functions you want to bind via `spring.cloud.function.definition` property delimiting function definitions with `;`. For example, `--spring.cloud.function.definition=foo;bar|baz` where you are binding two functions; one is `foo` and second is `bar|baz` (composition of two functions).
The binding names will be based on the naming convention. For example, `foo-in-0` and `foo-out-0`.

Comment: How will the binding name be for piped (composed) ones - foo;bar|baz ? And, what should I be mapping to my custom topic in Kafka Binder please ?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal - based on my testing it seems to use a pipe in the name, eg. bar|baz-in-0, bar|baz-out-0

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 functions in one application (foo; bar) where both functions have the same destination?

Comment: @BenKeil, were you able to resolve it?